# sqlite-net-pcl does not work in Windows Phone

Tags: c#, sqlite, xamarin, windows-phone-8.1, sqlite-net

I followed this guide https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/working-with/databases/#PCL_WinRT, but i have problem after run app on device (on emulator WP 8.1 and android platform works fine):

```
 Exception thrown: 'System.DllNotFoundException' in
 SQLitePCLRaw.provider.e_sqlite3.ni.DLL Exception thrown:
 'System.TypeInitializationException' in SQLite-net.ni.DLL
```

[image: screen references]

Can help me somebody?

Answer (score 0):

I was at the same point as you are. You need to inlucde Visual Studio C++ 2013 Runtime package to use the SQLite-Database in WindowsPhone.

> NOTE 1: Windows 8.1 and Windows Phone 8.1 require you to include the
>   Visual Studio C++ 2013 Runtime Package in order for
>   SQLitePCL.raw_basic to work.
>
> NOTE 2: Windows Phone 8 Silverlight requires you to download
>   [Precompiled Binaries for Windows Phone 8 VSIX](http://www.sqlite.org/download.html#wp8) and install in Visual
>   Studio; this enables the SQLite for Windows Phone Extension that you
>   can then add to your app.

You can find the above infos and a sample project (xamarin-todo-sample) on [this github page](https://github.com/conceptdev/xamarin-forms-windows-preview/tree/master/Todo). This helped me to solve the problems

Comment: Thanks for quikly answer, but C++ 2013 Runtime Package include in my project. It's does not work for me :(
I tried run sample and i see very slow query to sqlite on windows phone, simple insert  query - 3289 mileseconds. On android insert - 60 mileseconds. Very strange.